# SSH handshake error. Bild VM via packer

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine

I get the following debug errors:

```
2017/04/06 12:20:29 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:29 starting remote command: esxcli --formatter csv network vm port list -w 16370647
2017/04/06 12:20:29 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:29 [INFO] Attempting SSH connection...
2017/04/06 12:20:29 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:29 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
2017/04/06 12:20:29 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:29 handshaking with SSH
2017/04/06 12:20:30 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:30 handshake error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password keyboard-interactive], no supported methods remain
2017/04/06 12:20:30 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:30 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password keyboard-interactive], no supported methods remain
2017/04/06 12:20:30 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:30 [DEBUG] Detected authentication error. Increasing handshake attempts.
2017/04/06 12:20:37 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:37 [INFO] Attempting SSH connection...
2017/04/06 12:20:37 packer: 2017/04/06 12:20:37 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
```

json-file::

```
{
    "variables": {
        "type": "vmware-iso",
        "architecture": "386",
        "name": "alpine",
        "monitor": "vga=788",
        "remote_type": "esx5",
        "remote_host": "ххх.ххх.ххх.хx",
        "remote_datastore": "ххх",
        "remote_username": "root",
        "remote_password": "qwerty",
        "guest": "otherlinux-64",
        "disk_size": "7000",
        "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
        "iso_url": "alpine.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "204435de634d07e9fd0ead96f1e84043",
        "http_directory": ".",
        "http_port_min": "8000",
        "http_port_max": "9001",
        "cores": "1",
        "memsize": "512",
        "numvcpus": "1",
        "netname": "LAN-xxx.xxx",
        "virtualDev": "e1000"
    },
    "builders": [{
            "type": "vmware-iso",
            "communicator": "ssh",
            "boot_command": [
                "root<enter><wait>",
                "ifconfig eth0 up && udhcpc -i eth0<enter><wait5>",
                "wget http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/answers<enter><wait>",
                "setup-alpine -f answers<enter><wait10>",
                "qwerty<enter><wait10>",
                "qwerty<enter><wait10>",
                "<wait10><wait10><wait10>",
                "<wait10><wait10><wait10>",
                "<wait10><wait10><wait10>"
            ],
            "remote_type": "{{user `remote_type`}}",
            "remote_host": "{{user `remote_host`}}",
            "remote_datastore": "{{user `remote_datastore`}}",
            "remote_username": "{{user `remote_username`}}",
            "remote_password": "{{user `remote_password`}}",
            "guest_os_type": "{{user `guest`}}",
            "vm_name": "{{user `name`}}",
            "disk_size": "10000",
            "ssh_username": "root",
            "ssh_password": "qwerty",
            "ssh_port": 22,
            "http_directory": "{{user `http_directory`}}",
            "iso_checksum_type": "{{user `iso_checksum_type`}}",
            "iso_url": "{{user `iso_url`}}",
            "iso_checksum": "{{user `iso_checksum`}}",
            "http_port_min": "{{user `http_port_min`}}",
            "http_port_max": "{{user `http_port_max`}}",
            "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
            "keep_registered": true,
            "shutdown_command": "echo 'shutdown -P now' > shutdown.sh; echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S sh 'shutdown.sh'",

            "vmx_data": {
                "cpuid.coresPerSocket": "{{user `cores`}}",
                "memsize": "{{user `memsize`}}",
                "numvcpus": "{{user `numvcpus`}}",
                "ethernet0.networkName": "LAN-xxx.xx",
                "ethernet0.present": "true",
                "ethernet0.virtualDev": "e1000",
                "ethernet0.startConnected": "true",
                "RemoteDisplay.vnc.webSocket.port": "5900"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is your problem ??

Comment: SSH handshake error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please provide more information as to where and how you got the said error (e.g. what program you are working on, language used, particular code or process that triggered this error, etc.)

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Any help?